# To send username and password in url

Tags: java, security, url

For a login Page, i wanted to send the *username and password* via headers in a api, using the post method.

Is this safe? Are there any other better methods to achieve this?

Comment: since its a post method why not send these details as payload and password must be encrypted.

Comment: As long as your are using https and the server certificate validation passes, it is safe.

Comment: if the password is encrypted and sent via POST , then is it secure????

Comment: Can it be decrypted by other side????

Comment: @Pooja yes the encryption and decryption algo should be same

Comment: Ok. If i want to test it in postman, then how will i get the encrypted password???

Comment: If i want to test it in postman, then how will i send the encrypted password???